# SSMS in Redgate tool sql source control when Commit the changes in source control then "Command Line Error" occured

Tags: sql-server, perforce, redgate

i linked my database to perforce work-space using redgate tool in sql source control,but when i commit the change to source control that is nothing but my p4 work-space given error..like..

```
"Command line error"
```

Command:

```
P4 -s submit -d "adding" "C:\P4\webteam\SANDBOXES\mysandbox\DemoWebsite\EmployeeManagement\..."

Output:
error: No files to submit from the default changelist.

exit: 1

Exit code:
1

 - sending file to source control server
showing  false
```

I think some what about to change in .xml file that exixting  Command line hook folder i.e perforce.xml and template.xml
but what I need to change that I don't know.

Comment: Are you asking what "No files to submit from the default changelist" means? It means that either you haven't made any changes at all, or you made changes, but you put them in a numbered pending changelist, and you did not specify that changelist number on your submit commit (using `submit -c`). Before you try your submit, run `p4 opened` and paste the output to your question.

Comment: yes i m asking same "no file to submit from the default changelist " but i hav made changes in script and also specify the submit command in perforce.xml and template.xlm as "P4 -s submit -d "($Message)" "($ScriptsFolder)...""

Comment: Did you "p4 add" the files to put them in your default changelist?

Comment: yes there is already present in .xml file.                                                                                          <element>
      <key type="string">Commit</key>
      <value version="1" type="GenericHookCommand">
        <CommandLine>P4 -s submit -d "($Message)" "($ScriptsFolder)..."</CommandLine>
        <Verify>exitCode == 0 &amp;&amp; !output.Contains("Error:")</Verify>
      </value>
    </element>         this content are there........